# How to modify a request being sent in a HTTP proxy?

Tags: c#, node.js, windows, http, http-proxy

I'm very new to this proxy stuff. I've recently installed [Burp Suite HTTP Proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/getting-started) (Community Version). I want to be able to intercept a request being sent from a website, modify it, and then approve it to forward it. I'm using [instagram's](https://instagram.com) website for example. I send a message through the Direct Message feature on the website. Now, the message isn't going to send obviously because my proxy has intercepted it and awaiting further orders on what to do with the interception. How can I simply just change what I wrote, and then forward it? If Burp isn't the right tool for this, please tell me. I'm willing to try anything to make this work. I know this question might be dumb for some of you who are experienced, but even just opening the application already has me scratchin' my head! Any help is appreciated. (This is for testing purposes).

This is what I see when I first open the application:
[I've already opened a browser inside Burp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXW0d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply right click on the request and choose *send to repeater*. Then go to the repeater tab and do what you want.

As an alternative, when the proxy captures the request, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> which sends the captured request to the repeater tab and opens the tab for you.

In the repeater tab you can modify the request and the send it as many times as you wish.

Comment: But after it sends, do I just turn intercept off so it can run?

Comment: Yes you can turn it off. Note that no matter you leave the interceptor on or off, you can use the repeater.